# Could there be a lawsuit against actionnetwork.org for sending unstoppable spam?

Tags: united-states, spam

actionnetwork.org is a mass-email tool for politics. Once a user has signed up for ANY campaign newsletter that is built on actionnetwork, all other campaigns on actionnetwork are free to spam the user. There is no way to unsubscribe from all actionnetwork emails. They will only let you unsubscribe from one newsletter at a time - and there are thousands. Is this illegal in the US? Can they be sued?

Answer (score 5):

### Such a lawsuit will fail

The [CAN-SPAM](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business) act applies to **commercial** emails. The emails you describe are **political** emails and outside its jurisdiction.

All you can do is tune your junk mail filter.